# How do I call a function is already used from another function in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.
The function `clickOnTableRow()` is used by a click event (It's to change a table row color when clicked and back to what it was originally when another row clicked), and I'd like to make it automatically, so I set a Bootstrap switch. By toggling it, the table row color would be changed row by row automatically every three seconds. I  tried to call `clickOnTableRow()` again from `switchHanlder()`, but it didn't work. Is there another way could do it?

Thanks in advance!!

```
class Student extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedRow: 0,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label class="switch switch-pill switch-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked onChange={this.switchHanlder}/>
          <span class="switch-slider" />
        </label>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="table-hover">
            {this.props.data.map((student, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}
                    onClick={(e) => this.clickOnTableRow(i)}
                    className={this.state.selectedRow === i ? "table-selected" : "" }>
                  <td>{student.name}</td>
                  <td>{student.age}</td>
                  <td>{student.address}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  clickOnTableRow = (selectedRow) => {
    if (selectedRow !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ selectedRow });
    }
  };

  switchHanlder (e) {
    var selectedRow = 0;
    function f() {
      console.log("selectedRow:", selectedRow);
      this.clickOnTableRow(selectedRow); //it didn't work
      selectedRow++;
      if(selectedRow < 5 ){
        setTimeout(f, 3000);
      }
    }
    f();
  }
}

export default Student;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `arrow` function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`

```js
class Student extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedRow: 0,
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label class="switch switch-pill switch-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked onChange={this.switchHanlder}/>
          <span class="switch-slider" />
        </label>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="table-hover">
            {this.props.data.map((student, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}
                    onClick={(e) => this.clickOnTableRow(i)}
                    className={this.state.selectedRow === i ? "table-selected" : "" }>
                  <td>{student.name}</td>
                  <td>{student.age}</td>
                  <td>{student.address}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  clickOnTableRow = (selectedRow) => {
    if (selectedRow !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ selectedRow });
    }
  };

  switchHanlder = (e) => {
    var selectedRow = 0;
    var _this = this
    function f() {
      console.log("selectedRow:", selectedRow);
      _this.clickOnTableRow(selectedRow); //it didn't work
      selectedRow++;
      if(selectedRow < 5 ){
        setTimeout(f, 3000);
      }
    }
    f();
  }
}

export default Student;
```

Comment: It didn't work. It showed the same error( TypeError: Cannot read property 'clickOnTableRow' of undefined)

Comment: Why you need the `f` function ?, if you wrote your code inside `f` function right inside the `switchHandler` function, your original code would work.

Comment: @thelonglqd inner f function, have setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a constructor function, I always do it like this way :

```
class Student extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      selectedRow: 0,
    }
    this.clickOnTableRow = this.clickOnTableRow.bind(this)
    this.switchHanlder = this.switchHanlder.bind(this)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label class="switch switch-pill switch-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked onChange={this.switchHanlder}/>
          <span class="switch-slider" />
        </label>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="table-hover">
            {this.props.data.map((student, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}
                    onClick={(e) => this.clickOnTableRow(i)}
                    className={this.state.selectedRow === i ? "table-selected" : "" }>
                  <td>{student.name}</td>
                  <td>{student.age}</td>
                  <td>{student.address}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  clickOnTableRow = (selectedRow) => {
    if (selectedRow !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ selectedRow });
    }
  };

  switchHanlder (e) {
    var selectedRow = 0;
    function f() {
      console.log("selectedRow:", selectedRow);
      this.clickOnTableRow(selectedRow); //it didn't work
      selectedRow++;
      if(selectedRow < 5 ){
        setTimeout(f, 3000);
      }
    }
    f();
  }
}

export default Student;
```